# can't pickle _thread.RLock objects - Pyspark model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, pickle, random-forest

I created a RandomForest model with PySpark. 
I need to save this model as a file with .pkl extension, for this I used the pickle library, but when I go to use it I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-76-bf32d5617a63> in <module>()
      2 
      3 filename = "drive/My Drive/Progetto BigData/APPOGGIO/Modelli/SVM/svm_sentiment_analysis"
----> 4 pickle.dump(model, open(filename, "wb"))

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

***Is it possible to use PICKLE with a PySPark model like RandomForest or can it only be used with a Scikit-learn model ???***

This is my code:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol = "label", featuresCol = "word2vect", weightCol = "classWeigth", seed = 0, maxDepth=10, numTrees=100, impurity="gini")
model = rf.fit(train_df)

# Save our model into a file with the help of pickle library
filename = "drive/My Drive/Progetto BigData/APPOGGIO/Modelli/SVM/svm_sentiment_analysis"
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, "wb"))
```

***My environment is Google Colab*** 
I need to transform the model into a **PICKLE file** to create a webapp, to save it I normally use the ***.save(path)*** method, in this case ***I don't need*** the *.save* . 
Is it possible that a PySpark model cannot be transformed into a file?

*Thanks in advance!!*